# HTML & JavaScript - mute button makes nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added a toggle mute button for my fullscreen autoplay video but unfortunately it doesn't work.

If I click on the button, happens nothing. I have no error in the console.

**How can I fix that?** My `<video>` flags:

```
preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="true" muted="" playsinline="" style="position: absolute;"
```

I tried:

```
$(".bg-video-button-muted").click(function(){
    if ($(this).prev().find("#video_background").prop('muted')) {
        $(this).prev().find("#video_background").prop('muted', false);
        $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-volume-off").addClass("fa-volume-up");
    }
    else {
        $(this).prev().find("#video_background").prop('muted', true);
        $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-volume-up").addClass("fa-volume-off");
    }
    
    return false;
});
```

And thats the code on my website for the button:

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="bg-video-button-muted"><i class="fa fa-volume-off"></i></a>
```

If you need anything from my website files for the button, feel free to add a comment.

Comment: At what point do you include the javascript? A usual cause for stuff like this is that the DOM has not been constructed when you try to query it...

Comment: Can you add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably in a Stack Snippet, that reproduces the problem, instead of small, disparate snippets of your HTML and JS code?

Comment: i use ```<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>``` to include the javascript.

Comment: I don't know if that's reproducible. Because it works on my other website, but that uses other scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work just fine, I added an example below and it work.

I think the problem with your code is one of the following problem.

1- you are not finding the current element with the fallowing code

```
$(this).prev().find
```

2- you are binding the click event before the renderer is finished, you could then Add `$(document).ready` or add the script at the bottom of you site.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".bg-video-button-muted").click(function(){
    if ($("#video_background").prop('muted')) {
        $("#video_background").prop('muted', false);
       // $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-volume-off").addClass("fa-volume-up");
        console.log("unmute")
    }
    else {
        $("#video_background").prop('muted', true);
       // $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-volume-up").addClass("fa-volume-off");
         console.log("mute")
    }
    
    return false;
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" role="button" class="bg-video-button-muted">mute</a>


<video id="video_background" width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.quackit.com/video/pass-countdown.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
```